# Javascript backspace by default issue....going back a page by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript backspace by default problem…Going back a page.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587525/javascript-backspace-by-default-problem-going-back-a-page)

The issue I am having is when you type a list of phone numbers into the list and then when you click one to edit it, if you backspace to delete the number, it will mess the entire list up by going back one page....i am fully aware that this is because the default back page is backspace and thats why its doing that but I really want it to not backpage when I use backspace to delete a number from the list.....

So what I am saying basically is how can I disable backspace to back page......

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bikbouche1/QVUHU/67/

Comment: working perfect on fiddle, where is the problem?

Comment: I think he wants Delete to delete the last entry made AFTER clicking submit.

Comment: You posted the exact same question yesterday... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587525/javascript-backspace-by-default-problem-going-back-a-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to block backspace you can use this:

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var keyCode = evt.keyCode;
    if (keyCode == 8) { // backspace
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you can override the Backspace button action using the following code snippet:

```
function suppressBackspace(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

    if (evt.keyCode == 8 && !/input|textarea/i.test(target.nodeName)) {
        return false;
    }
}

document.onkeydown = suppressBackspace;
document.onkeypress = suppressBackspace;
```

This should work in all browsers and it also filters out events that originated from an input or textarea element.

So if you want to use the backspace button for another action you can call the function there where it suppresses the default browser action.

Comment: Thanks Jules, I added the code snipped you gave at the buttom of the JS part but it still did not work....After I had a list of numbers added to that list and tried to delete one of the numbers using backspace screen blinked and all the numbers were gone....PS: I didnt say anything about a submit button..All i said is its hard to delete a number from the list unless you highlight it all and click delete...You cant use backspace to delete...

Answer (score 0):

Backspace only makes the page go back if you don't have focus in a form field. With your Jsfiddle, I didn't have your issue.